# How to fix odd value returned from select list populated by database

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP I'm populating a dropdown list with values taken from a MySQL database. The list displays fine, my problem comes when I try to retrieve the selected value. I'm defining a variable and passing it the dropdownlist name for the POST array:

```
$variable = $_POST['dropdownlist'];
```

but the contents of $variable are \{value}"

Why is it putting in the \{ and }", and how do I get rid of them to get a value I can actually use?

Comment: The backslash to me looks like something might also be getting escaped, check for magic quotes to be turned off and if they're on you can run the input  through stripslashes()

Comment: run through stripslashes() and mysql_real_escape_string() without making any difference

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting curly brackets as part of the value then the chances are they are their in your HTML code. Your code is likely something like echo '{$value}'; rather than echo "{$value}"; or something similar.

Comment: Was using echo $value without any curly brackets or quotes

Comment: In which case how did the information get into the database? Are they present if viewing the database via phpMyAdmin? Click view source in your browser, and show us what the HTML looks like, it's extremely likely that they are present there.

Comment: Data fine in the database, but think I've found the bug. I'd used a function from a book to populate all the select lists, and part of its code was:

print "\n\t<option value ="\{$result}\">{$result}";
   
I've changed it and it looks OK in the source view now, so I'll try pulling the values out to see if that's the problem sorted. Thanks for you help.